# How do I create a shared service for my typescript class instances to talk to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to provide a shared service for my various class instances to talk to. I do not want each of these instances creating their own private instance of this shared service.

For example, let's say I have 5 instances of my `MarketManager` class. These 5 instances are currently making a lot of overlapping API calls. As such I have developed an aggregator class called `APIManager` that is responsible for periodically getting API data and rendering it available for the 5 `MarketManager` instances.

If I were to call `let myAPI = new APIManager` in my `MarketManager` class, I would create 5 `APIManager` classes, correct? This would not help my goal of reducing the number of API calls I am making.

A solution that comes to mind would be to have `APIManager` host an API on localhost at a given port, say `localhost:13337`. This seems quite excessive, as I only want to make this service available within my nodejs app. Is there a way for talking to different instances without instantiating them?

For added info, I am currently using TypeScript in my project. I have an index.js file that sets up 5 `MarketManager` instances and those then execute my application logic. I would like to make a shared service available to all 5 instances without having each of those instances instantiate the shared service.

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-static

Comment: Can I use static methods to access state? I would have thought that a class would not have state until it has been initialized. The `APIManager` class would need to be making API calls and managing an object of the latest results (to then serve to the other instances via a public function).

Comment: You just need to initialize it at the start. Ideally you'd have a ApiManager.getManager() as static accessor which returns the singleton. If it's not initialized, it will initialize the singleton. The singleton is then returned everytime.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Either use a singleton, or pass a reference to the marketmanager instance around your app. You may also be interested in Dependency Injection: a way to pass a service to your instances: https://dev.to/azure/dependency-injection-in-javascript-101-2b1e